# Autocomplete with c# dictionary

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using kendo UI (telerik) and I want to add a datasource that is a Dictionary parsed to object from c# to js. How can I take object values and add them to an autocomplete input? I have this code:

```
var availableCategories = JSON.parse(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.AvailableCategoriesJSON))));

$(document).ready(function () {

var data=availableCategories;

$("#categories").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: data,
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Select category...",
        separator: ", "
    });
```

and the input:

```
<input id="categories" />
```

Comment: If you have the available categories in your viewmodel, why are you encoding to and decoding from JSON? Just output in array syntax.

Comment: Because after I select a category, I will save the category Id. And it's easy to do that from a js object.

Comment: What issues are you having? What doesn't works? Can you show your `AvailableCategoriesJSON` content ?

Comment: AvailableCategoriesJSON is a C# Dictionary<Guid, string> that I'm converting to a js object that looks like { Guid : string } and I want to use this object as dataSource for an autocomplete input

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, your `availableCategories` object will be something like this:

```
[{"0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e": "category 1"},
 {"7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7": "category 2"}]
```

But you neet to tell the widget which property it will work with. So I suggest you to dinamically create another *dummy* property, e.g. `text`:

```
data.forEach(x => {
    var k = Object.keys(x);

    x.text = x[k[0]];
});

// Shorthand:
data.forEach(x => x.text = x[Object.keys(x)[0]]);
```

Then you add this option:

```
dataTextField: "text"
```

Result:

```
var data = [{"0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e": "category 1"},
            {"7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7": "category 2"}];

data.forEach(x => x.text = x[Object.keys(x)[0]]);

$("#categories").kendoAutoComplete({
      dataSource: data,
      filter: "startswith",
      placeholder: "Select category...",
      separator: ", ",
      dataTextField: "text",
      select: function(e) {
        console.log("Selected item", e.dataItem);
      }
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IrokE)